# If the reduction is smooth and projective, can I conclude the same about the scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, arithmetic-geometry, projective-schemes

Let $X$ be a $R$-scheme, where $R$ is a dvr.
Suppose that the reduction of $X$ (over the closed point of $\mathrm{Spec} \ R$) is smooth and projective. Does this imply that $X$ is smooth and projective? Smoothness might get messed up by the generic fibre, but what about projectiveness?

Is $X\to \mathrm{Spec} R$ projective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider a finite unramified extension $R'/R$ such that $R'$ is integral with two maximal ideals. Let $X$ be $\mathrm{Spec}(R')$ minus one closed point. Then $X$ is quasi-finite, étale, but not finite (hence not projective) over $R$, and its closed fiber is smooth and finite.